# Как переопределить параметр name у input в html

Tags: html

Есть такая задача, одно поле , две кнопки
При нажатии на одну кнопку ищет в Google , при нажатии на вторую ищет в Яндекс.

Хочется сделать это все без JS.
В данном случае не работает кнопка Яндекс, потому что в поле input , name  = text должно быть.
А в случае с Гуглом , должно быть равно "q"

Вот мой код:

```
<head>
<!-- Заголовок -->
    <title>Поиск</title>
</head>
<!-- Тело -->
<body align= "center">
<h1>Search</h1>
    <form id="search" align= "center" action="https://www.google.ru/search"method ="get">
    <input size= "30" autofocus name= "q" required placeholder= "Запрос" type="text"/>
    </form>
    <p><input type= "submit" value="Поиск в Google"/>
    <input type= "submit" formaction= "https://yandex.ru/search/" value="Поиск в Yandex" form="search"/></p>
</body>
```

Comment: Скорее всего без JS это реализовать невозможно. Вам надо как-то определять какой именно экшен должен отработать. Или ещё одна форма для второй кнопки.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Без js сложно представить, как такое сделать.

```html
<head>
<style>
body {
    background-color: #1f1a1a
}
h1 {
    background-color: #00b33c;
}
</style>
<!-- Заголовок -->
    <title>Поиск</title>
</head>
<!-- Тело -->
<body align= "center">
<h1>Search</h1>
    <input size= "30" autofocus id="query" name= "q" placeholder="Запрос" type="text" required>
    <p>
        <button type= "button" id="googleSearchBtn" onclick="googleSearch()">Поиск в google</button>
        <button type= "button" id="yandexSearchBtn" onclick="yandexSearch()">Поиск в Yandex</button>
    </p>
</body>
<script>
    function googleSearch(){
        var query = document.getElementById("query").value;
        window.open("https://google.com/search?q="+query, '_blank');
    }

    function yandexSearch(){
        var query = document.getElementById("query").value;
        window.open("https://yandex.ru/search?text="+query, '_blank');
    }
</script>
```

Comment: А как сделать чтобы открывался в том же окне поиск?

Comment: @OWGrant24, убрать '_blank' из window.open()

Answer (score 2):

Почему так сразу категорично "Без js невозможно"?
Вариантов реализации куча. 
Вот один из примеров php.

```php
<?php
?>
<head>
    <title>Поиск</title>
</head>
<body align= "center">
<h1>Search</h1>
<form id="search" align= "center" action="#" method="post" target="_blank">
    <input size= "30" autofocus name= "q" required placeholder= "Запрос" type="text"/>
<p>
    <button name="google" type="submit" formmethod="post">Поиск в Google</button>
    <button name="yandex" type="submit" formmethod="post">Поиск в Yandex</button>
</p>
</form>
</body>
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['q']) and !empty($_POST['q'])){
        if(isset($_POST['google'])){
            header('Location: https://www.google.ru/search?q='.$_POST['q'],true,301);
        } elseif(isset($_POST['yandex'])){
            header('Location: https://yandex.ru/search?text='.$_POST['q'],true,301);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Что-то у меня код этот не заработал(